# Zoom страницы

Tags: javascript

В браузерах есть функция Ctrl+колёсико мыши, которая увеличивает или уменьшает страницу, но не все пользователи знают о такой функции. Как с помощью javascript управлять параметрами этого объекта браузера, нажимая на определённый объект на странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, из javascript управлять зумом нельзя, только отслеживать. Как вариант - сделать несколько css файлов и менять их параметр disabled по клику по определенному объекту.

Comment: А каким образом можно отследить?

Comment: Например, вставить на страницу два элемента: у одного ширина в процентах, а у другого в пикселях и проверять отношение их длин (если проценты считаются от ширины экрана). Но тогда еще придется отслеживать изменение размеров окна.
http://novemberborn.net/2007/12/javascriptpage-zoom-ff3-128

Другой вариант - просто отслеживать нажатия клавиш и колесика мыши. Возможно, писать в куки.

Comment: ммм, второй вариант интересен)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте jQuery:

```
$(document).animate({width:"+=100px",heigth:"+=100px"},time);
```

time - это время, за которое анимация увеличения произойдет. Я думаю, остальное понятно.

Comment: за что минус?((

Comment: Минусовал не я, но со своей стороны замечу, что не представляю, как можно изменить ширину объекта document, это концептуально неподходящий объект. Ближайшее к этому - body, но изменение его ширины, конечно, не будет масштабировать все внутренние элементы.